# How to hide window close, minimize and maximize buttons on Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer, gui

[image: Diagram showing the close, minimize and maximize buttons]

On Windows XP, is there a way to hide these buttons normally present on each window?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by hiding the buttons? Are you trying to make it so the window cannot be closed/resized, or do you want to hide them for aesthetics?

Comment: @iglvzx Aesthetics. I use a program called *Taskbar Shuffle* which allows full manipulation of windows using the task bar alone; so the buttons are redundant and I'd prefer to hide them entirely (years of experience still goad me to click them sometimes and I want to train away from that).

Answer (score 4):

The presence or absence of those buttons is controlled by the program that owns the window.  For example, dialog boxes (pop ups that require an answer before continuing) don't generally have these buttons or they are disabled.  If you (the user) could somehow force the buttons to be hidden you could easily cause difficulty in using many programs.

Comment: If the user could somehow force Windows XP to blue screen he could easily cause difficulty as well, yet we can do just that. Are you sure there's no way to hide those buttons?